# Community user "stealing" tags?

Tags: support, tags, revisions-list, community-user

On September 29th, I created the [ebean](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ebean) tag for [How mature is Ebean or Siena?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4349341/how-mature-is-ebean-or-siena)
Today, while checking the tag description, I saw that the [creator](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/7593827/revisions) seems to be [Community user](https://stackoverflow.com/users/-1/community).

Why is that? Why has the Community user "stolen" the spot as author of the tag?

Comment: Lots of related questions. Have you checked them?

Comment: @Wivani didn't see any question about this specific issue, do you have a link? I only saw related to Community user asking what it was, etc...

Comment: I - mistakingly? - thought all the topics about Community user would give some idea on how the process works. (Undid the downvote)

Comment: @Wivani no worries :)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The creator of a tag is not the creator of the related tag wiki: The creator of a tag is the first user who used it in a question, and so far it is not reported in any place. (There is a feature request about showing who created the tag, though.)

What you see in the history of a tag wiki is the creator of the tag wiki. You can only suggest edits for the tag wiki, with the reputation you have. If the tag wiki didn't exist before, then the Community user creates it for you.

Comment: What I did was edit the linked question and add the ebean tag into it. The tag didn't exist previously. That shouldn't count as me creating it?

Comment: ah, ok, that clarifies a lot. Thanks! :)

Comment: Very well said, it's really not clear or trivial..