# A tag I've created now shows as created by the Community ♦ user; why?

Tags: support, tags

A while back I've created a new tag [xsd-1.1] ([on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/xsd-1.1)). It now shows to have been created by the "Community" user; why is this?

Comment: You're probably looking at the tag *wiki* revision history. That has nothing to do with who actually created the tag itself.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are talking about the tag wiki. If yes, then: you don't actually have a privilege to create tag wikis and edit them instantly, this privilege is achieved at **20k**.

Until this moment, the tag is created by [Community ♦](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/-1/community) and your tag  edits are just suggestions. They could be rejected, then it would appear that you didn't create any wiki actually, so it is better to attribute the creation of wiki to [Community ♦](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/-1/community), just in case :)

Comment: Actually, found this http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/108319/community-user-stealing-tags which seems to explain how the process works; I never asked with that tag, so that explains it. Thank you.